# shadows a parameter when single parameter on constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, shadow

Hi I was coding simple class followed by sample code in web.
This code works fine without an error.

```
class Shape{
      protected:
              int width,height;

      public:
             Shape(int a = 0, int b=0)
             {
             width = a;
             height = b;         
                       }

};
class regSquare: public Shape{
      public:
             regSquare( int a=0, int b=0)
             {
              Shape(a, b);
             }    
};
```

but when I change my to have only one parameter for the constructor such as

```
class Shape{
      protected:
              int width;
      public:
             Shape(int a = 0)
             {
             width = a;

                       }

};
class regSquare: public Shape{
      public:
             regSquare(int a = 0)
             {
              Shape(a);
             }    
};
```

it occurring error with this massage

> 'error: declaration of `a' shadows a parameter'

I have no idea what is wrong about my code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most likely neither version does what you want, though! The code

```
regSquare(int a = 0, int b = 0) {
    Shape(a, b);
}
```

Does **not** initialize the `Shape` subobject of your `regSquare` object! Instead, it creates a temporary object of type `Shape` with the parameters `a` and `b`. The one parameter version does something similar:

```
Shape(a);
```

defines a default constructed object of type `Shape` called `a`. You probably meant to use the initializer list to pass the constructor arguments to the `Shape` subobject, e.g.:

```
reqSquare(int a = 0, int b = 0)
    : Shape(a, b) {
}
```

or

```
regSquare(int a = 0)
   : Shape(a) {
}
```

Comment: upper one is exactly the same as example on the web. and it still not working with add ":" in front of Shape(a). any suggestion?

Comment: @user842589: Note the exact placement of the parenthesis: the change is more than adding a colon in front of `Shape`! You need to mention the base classes (and members) you need to initialize in the member initializer list which precedes the body of the constructor. I can reproduce your error with the original code and my change does fix it. If the first example is exactly as taken from the Web, you have chosen a bad source for an example as it behaves as I stated and I'm pretty sure that is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Because in single arguement compiler takes it as object name and creating an object so it is creating a conflict.